# How to sort file names numerically

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting, integer

I have filenames as such: savedrecs(1), savedrecs(2)...savedrecs(11), etc., and I use the code:

```
import sys
import os
import glob
directory = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

for folder in directory:
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "savedrecs(*).txt")):
        print file
        with open(file) as f:
            a=sum(not line.strip() for line in f)
            print a
```

Here, the (*) stands for the file number. However, when I run the code, the outcomes correspond to the files numbered 1,11,12,13,2,3,4 respectively, instead of this preferred order: 1,2,3,4,(...),11,12,13. Is there a way I can define the * as an integer and then in some way adapt that to this code?

Comment: maybe you could keep it as tuple `(11, "savedrecs(11).txt")` and sort tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like...

```
import sys
import os
import glob
directory = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

files = sorted(glob.glob(folder+'/directory*/savedrec*'))
for i in files:
    print i
    with open(i) as f:
        a=sum(not line.strip() for line in f)
        print a
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should treat the number as an int rather than string and do the sorting appropriately

```
fns = ['savedrecs('+str(i)+').txt' for i in range(1,20)]
def key_fn(x):
    return int(re.findall(r"savedrecs\((\d+)\).txt", fns[0])[0])

print sorted(fns, key=key_fn)
```

So in your code, you can have something like:

```
for file in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "savedrecs(*).txt")), key = key_fn):
```

Answer (score 0):

Garrett R, I think you mean this:

```
def key_fn(x):
    return int(re.findall(r"savedrecs\((\d+)\).txt", x)[0])
```